# What is the difference between "rake db:seed" and rake db:fixtures:load"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, fixtures

I am new to Ruby and Rails and am curious about something.

In two different tutorials I am looking at they use different methods for populating a database with basic test information.

One uses "rake db:seed" to pull from a text file with sample data.

The other uses "rake db:fixtures:load".

To me they appear to do the exact same thing.

Do they, or am I missing something here? (Highly likely)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`rake db:seed`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ec54acd1e01374f0b5b495d7659181d7382e119e/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L178) loads the data from db/seeds.rb into the database. This is generally used for development and production databases. It's permanent data that you use to start an empty application. More information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data).

[`rake db:fixtures:load`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ec54acd1e01374f0b5b495d7659181d7382e119e/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L185) loads the test fixtures into the test database. This is temporary data used solely by the tests. You can think of fixtures as [sample data](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures).

Comment: It's actually `rake db:seed` (without 's' at the end)